# GATE extract NE from documents in German

Tags: nlp, gate

I need to extract people names from documents in German (not my native). After a bit of search, I've found GATE framework  which seems to support English, German and many other languages. The accuracy for English is quite decent, but it's unacceptable for German (see screenshots).

Here are the PRs:
[image]

And a chunk of highlighted people names:
[image]

A friend of mine says that none of these is a person name, so I wonder if I misconfigured something. Do I need to specify the language somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Install the `Language: German` plugin and use it. The accuracy is still poor though, at least for my case.